# JQuery each loop - do something with currently looped element

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have following `.each` jQuery loop.

```
$('.category').each(function(index) {
    if( $('.category > span').parent().next('h2') ) { 

        // get currently looped element which follows the condition
    }

});
```

**How to get currently looped element through `.each` inside the `if` statement?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to get currently looped element through .each inside the if
>   statement?

Use:

```
$(this) // represents current iterated element in wrapped set
```

Example:

```
$('.category').each(function(index) {
    if( $('.category > span').parent().next('h2') ) { 
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Note that you could also get DOM object instead of jQuery object by using `this` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.category').each(function(index) {
 var that = $(this);
 if( $('.category > span').parent().next('h2') ) { 
  // do something with `that`
 }
});
```

Cached `$(this)` to avoid having to look it up every time you use it…